# Semantic UI centre aligned login box?

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am using the Semantic UI framework for my website. I want to place the login box in the centre of the page.I want only the login box in the page. I don't understand how to centre aligned using Semantic UI 'grid classes'. Please help me how to fit the login box.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>my semantic website</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/semantic.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
<script src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>     </script>
<script src="../js/semantic.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="ui grid">
    <div class="one column row">
        <div class="ui padded grid">
            <div class="three column row">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="ui segment">
                        <h4 class="ui dividing header">Account Info</h4>
                        <div class="ui form">
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="username">Username: </label>
                                <div class="ui icon input">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">
                                    <i class="user icon"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                                <div class="ui icon input">
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
                                    <i class="lock icon"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="ui inverted blue button">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

See this code found in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/semantic-ui/SGmP3X6bkzE):

```
<div class="ui one column stackable center aligned page grid">
   <div class="column twelve wide">
       Your stuff here
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much friend.This is simple login box page only.So I want placed the box with in the page as Left,Right,top,bottom. Left and Right is well but Top and Bottom is not set properly.So any classes found for this.

Comment: Instead of "ui one column stackable center aligned page grid", change it to "ui stackable centered page grid"

Comment: `page grid` has been deprecated see [docs](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html#/overview).

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="ui column stackable center page grid">
  <div class="four wide column"></div><!-- empty div just padding -->
  <form class="ui six wide column form segment">
     <!-- login input fields go here -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="ui segment" style="margin: 0 auto;">
     <h4 class="ui dividing header">Account Info</h4>
     <div class="ui form">
         ........
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation, it works well.

[JsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/finello076/y9Lh17ov/)

HTML

```html
<div id="v-container" class="ui grid middle aligned">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column" align="middle">


      <div class="ui raised card ">
        <div class="ui small centered image no-background ">
          <img class="image-margin image-border" src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="ui header">TITLE</div>
          <div class="meta">
            SUBTITLE
          </div>
          <div class="description">
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, alias.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="extra content">
          extra content
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```css
#v-container {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-margin {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.image-border {
  border-radius: 4px !important;
}

.no-background {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```